# What are good sources for learning to hand draw cartesian and polar functions (and euclidean constructions)?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, graphing-functions, geometric-construction

I would like to get into hand plotting cartesian and polar functions as a hobby. What are good books/websites on this? I will absolutely look at youtube videos but I prefer books/websites because I find it a little easier to draw and read at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Well as you have stated YouTube is the best way to learn about hand plotting Cartesian and polar functions because there is such a variety to the types of methods there are and the unique view of this topic as taught by many different methods you might not even have thought of.
   [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHnbyuBSLRQ) (Many more with a simple google search this is just a sample)
2. Khan Academy has an entire series based on it which you should definitely give a try.
   [Khan Academy Graphing Polar Functions](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/double-integrals-a/v/polar-coordinates-1)
3. Lastly math related websites [SECURED] are the best at understanding because most likely they have comments enabled that allow you to ask if anything does not make sense to you. [Calculus/Polar Introduction](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Polar_Introduction)
   [Graphing Polar Equations](http://www.analyzemath.com/polarcoordinates/graphing_polar_equations.html)
4. Great sources of finding the more technical terms from common math problems would be to go onto a PDF 
   [Euclidean Constructions](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~droyster/courses/spring02/classnotes/Chapter03.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[C.a.R](http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/index.html) (Compass and Ruler) is a great program (free) for Euclidean construction.

Comment: This is similar to geogebra, which I also mess with on and off. But, I'm morbidly curious. All of the demo and application links seem to go nowhere.